# How to amending code to check if dropdown has value THEN search within that - ASP.NET/JS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor-pages

I have a table called myTable which displays a list of files. I then have a dropdown box and a search box.

All of this functionality works, if i search for a PO no, and if i select a vendor - this all works fine.

I want to amend my JS code for the search box to check if the dropdown is populated, and if it is then take that into consideration when searching for a PO no.

**My cshtml code is as follows:**

```
<h1 style="color: white">Purchase Orders</h1>
<p>
    <a asp-page="Create" style="color:white">Create File</a>
</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-check-inline pull-right">
            <label style="color:white">Search</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myInput" placeholder="Search Purchase Orders..." onkeyup="myFunction()" />
        </div>
        <select asp-items="@((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["test"])" id="vendor" onchange="myFunctionThree()">
            <option value="" disabled selected> Select a Vendor</option>
        </select>
        <input class="btn btn-light" value="Clear All Filters" onclick="history.go(0)" style="float: right">
        <table class="table" style="background-color: white" id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr class="header">
                    <th>
                        PO No.
                    </th>
                    
                    <th>
                        Haulier
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Comments
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Vendor
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Upload
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Date Uploaded
                    </th>
                    <th>Download</th>
                    <th>Delete Attachment</th>
                    <th>Notify</th>
                    <th>Sent</th>
                    <th>

                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @foreach (var item in Model.Files)
                {
                    if (item.FileType == "Purchase Order")
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
                            </td>

                            
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Haulier)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modeItem => item.Vendor.VendorName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a asp-page="Upload" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Upload File Attachment</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UploadDate)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @if (item.Attachment != null)
                                {
                                    <form asp-page-handler="Download" method="post" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Download">
                                    </form>
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @if (item.Attachment != null)
                                {
                                    <form asp-page-handler="Delete" method="post" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete Attachment">
                                    </form>
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @if (item.Attachment != null)
                                {
                                    <form asp-page-handler="Email" method="post" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Notify Vendor">
                                    </form>
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailSent)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a asp-page="/Admin/Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }

                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>


<script>



    //function for search bar
    function myFunction() {
        // Declare variables
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                    txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        tr[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }

    //function for dropdown menu
    function myFunctionThree()
    {
        // Declare variables
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("vendor");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I am not too familiar with js, so if someone could point me in the right direction please.

If you need any further info lmk.

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering around with the code, I found a solution that works.

**Finalised code(for search bar script):**

```
//function for search bar
    function myFunction() {
        // Declare variables
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue, dropdownValue, dropdownInput, dtd;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        dropdownInput = document.getElementById("vendor");
        dropdownValue = dropdownInput.value.toUpperCase();

        // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            dtd = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
            if (td) {
                    txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                    dropTxtValue = dtd.textContent || dtd.innerText;
                    if(dropdownValue == ""){
                        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                            tr[i].style.display = "";
                        } else {
                            tr[i].style.display = "none";
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        if((txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) && (dropTxtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(dropdownValue) > -1)){
                            tr[i].style.display = "";
                        }else{
                            tr[i].style.display = "none";
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```